# horizontal scroll bar in select box is not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, scrollbar

Trying to add horizontal scroll bar in select box. Some of the items of the select box have large text and I can't see that. So i tried to add css class as follows:

```
.selector_box{
    overflow:auto;
}

<div class="label_input">
    <%= f.label(:sample, "Books *", :class => 'label_required_field') %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:sample, @books.all, :id, :name, {:multiple => true, :class => 'selector_box'} )%>
</div>
```

The above code is not working for me and not finding a way to set a horizontal scroll bar. So how do i add a horizontal scroll bar to select box with auto re-sizing?

Comment: can you share your generated html

Comment: <select id="books" class="selector_box" name"books[books][]", multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1"> Book 1 </option>
   <option value="1"> Book 2 </option>
   <option value="1"> Book 3 </option> .....
   <option value="1"> Book 4 </option>
</select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your select box a width and instead of overflow: auto; have overflow: scroll;